# Сброс таймера после срабатывания всех счетчиков JS?

Tags: javascript

Было задание написать помощник измерения пульса.
(Условия:
    на странице находится три елемента поле для сообщений, поле ввода input + кнопка ввода, кнопка.
    пользователь нажимает кнопку в поле для сообщения появляется информация: "Измерение начнется через 5,4,3,...(таймер)"
    Измерение...
    после этого идет отсчет 15 секунд
    затем пользователь должен ввести количество ударов
    в сообщении должен появиться результат userInput * 4)

Написал. И вроде бы все норм, но повторно счетчики не запускаются?!
Не могу понять что и как сделать для правильного перезапуска таймеров!

```js
const message = document.getElementById('message');
const pulse = document.getElementById('number');
const startBtn = document.getElementById('start');
const resultBtn = document.getElementById('result');

const dataForTimer = {
    message1: 'Измерение начнется через',
    message2: 'Измерение...',
    timer1: 5,
    timer2: 15,
};

function Timer(element, textMessage, number, timer) {
    const elem = element;
    let count = number;
    let text = textMessage;
    let intervalId = null;

    this.showMessage = function () {
        intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            if (count <= 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
            console.log(intervalId);
            elem.innerHTML = ` ${text} ${count}`;
            count -= 1;
        }, 1000);

    };

    this.showNextMessage = function () {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.showMessage();
        }, timer);
    };
}

const timer1 = new Timer(message, dataForTimer.message1, dataForTimer.timer1);
const timer2 = new Timer(message, dataForTimer.message2, dataForTimer.timer2, '6000');

function showResult() {
    message.innerHTML = '';
    message.innerHTML = ` Ваш пульс ${+pulse.value * 4} ударов в минуту`;
}

startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pulse.value = '';
    timer1.showMessage();
    timer2.showNextMessage();
});

resultBtn.addEventListener('click', showResult);
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>
    <button id="start">START</button>
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="">
    <button id="result">RESULT</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо перенести и заменить:

```
const timer1 = new Timer(message, dataForTimer.message1, dataForTimer.timer1);
const timer2 = new Timer(message, dataForTimer.message2, dataForTimer.timer2, '6000');
```

В функцию:

```
   startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const timer1 = new Timer(message, dataForTimer.message1, dataForTimer.timer1, '0');
        const timer2 = new Timer(message, dataForTimer.message2, dataForTimer.timer2, '6000');
        pulse.value = '';
        timer1.showMessage();
        timer2.showNextMessage();
    });
```

Пример:

```js
const message = document.getElementById('message');
const pulse = document.getElementById('number');
const startBtn = document.getElementById('start');
const resultBtn = document.getElementById('result');

const dataForTimer = {
    message1: 'Измерение начнется через',
    message2: 'Измерение...',
    timer1: 5,
    timer2: 15,
};

function Timer(element, textMessage, number, timer) {
    const elem = element;
    let count = number;
    let text = textMessage;
    let intervalId = null;

    this.showMessage = function () {
        intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            if (count <= 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
            console.log(intervalId);
            elem.innerHTML = ` ${text} ${count}`;
            count -= 1;
        }, 1000);

    };

    this.showNextMessage = function () {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.showMessage();
        }, timer);
    };
}
function showResult() {
    message.innerHTML = '';
    message.innerHTML = ` Ваш пульс ${+pulse.value * 4} ударов в минуту`;
}

startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const timer1 = new Timer(message, dataForTimer.message1, dataForTimer.timer1, '0');
    const timer2 = new Timer(message, dataForTimer.message2, dataForTimer.timer2, '6000');
    pulse.value = '';
    timer1.showMessage();
    timer2.showNextMessage();
});

resultBtn.addEventListener('click', showResult);
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>
    <button id="start">START</button>
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="">
    <button id="result">RESULT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем тем, кто помог решить поставленную зажачу! 
Ну и благодаря своему ментору выяснил, что JS действительно многограныйн и классный язык!
Решений было несколько, но в итоге получился данный вариант.

```js
const message = document.getElementById('message');
const pulse = document.getElementById('number');
const startBtn = document.getElementById('start');
const resultBtn = document.getElementById('result');

const dataForTimer = {
  message1: 'Измерение начнется через',
  message2: 'Измерение...',
  timer1: 5,
  timer2: 15,
};

// eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
function Timer2(element, textMessage, number, runTimer) {
  const elem = element;
  let count = number;
  const text = textMessage;
  let intervalId = null;

  this.showMessage = () => {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        if (runTimer) {
          runTimer();
        }
      }
      elem.innerHTML = ` ${text} ${count}`;
      count -= 1;
    }, 1000);
  };
}

function showResult() {
  message.innerHTML = '';
  message.innerHTML = ` Ваш пульс ${+pulse.value * 4} ударов в минуту`;
}

function nextTimer() {
  const timer = new Timer2(message, dataForTimer.message2, dataForTimer.timer2);
  timer.showMessage();
}

startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const timer1 = new Timer2(message, dataForTimer.message1, dataForTimer.timer1, nextTimer);
  pulse.value = '';
  timer1.showMessage();
});

resultBtn.addEventListener('click', showResult);
```